# AttributeError: type object 'FrequentlyAskedQuestionView' has no attribute 'as_view'

Tags: python, django-rest-framework

I have a simple `FrequentlyAskedQuestion` model with a get request but when I try to unit test it returns `AttributeError: type object 'FrequentlyAskedQuestionView' has no attribute 'as_view'`

models.py

```py
    class FrequentlyAskedQuestion(models.Model):
        question = models.CharField(max_length=500)
        answer = models.TextField()
    
        def __str__(self):
            return self.question
```

serializers.py

```py
    class FrequentlyAskedQuestionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
        class Meta:
            model = FrequentlyAskedQuestion
    
            fields = ["pk", "question"]
    
    
    class FrequentlyAskedQuestionAndAnswerSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
        class Meta:
            model = FrequentlyAskedQuestion
    
            fields = ["question", "answer"]
```

views.py

```py
    class FrequentlyAskedQuestionView(APIView):
        def get(self, request, pk=None):
            if pk:
                try:
                    question = FrequentlyAskedQuestion.objects.get(pk=pk)
                except Appointment.DoesNotExist:
                    raise Http404
                serializer = FrequentlyAskedQuestionAndAnswerSerializer(question)
            else:
                question = FrequentlyAskedQuestion.objects.all()
                serializer = FrequentlyAskedQuestionSerializer(question, many=True)
            return Response(serializer.data)
test_views.py

    from django.urls import reverse
    from rest_framework.test import (
        APITestCase,
        APIRequestFactory,
    )
    
    from tech_support.models import FrequentlyAskedQuestion
    from tech_support.serializers import (
        FrequentlyAskedQuestionSerializer,
        FrequentlyAskedQuestionAndAnswerSerializer
    )
    from tech_support.views import FrequentlyAskedQuestionView
    
    factory = APIRequestFactory()
    
    
    class FrequentlyAskedQuestionView(APITestCase):
        def setUp(self):
            self.first_question = FrequentlyAskedQuestion.objects.create(
                question='first_test_question', answer='first_test_answer'
            )
            self.second_question = FrequentlyAskedQuestion.objects.create(
                question='second_test_question', answer='second_test_answer'
            )
            self.view = FrequentlyAskedQuestionView.as_view()
    
        def test_get_all_frequently_asked_questions(self):
            url_name = "frequently-asked-questions"
            request = factory.get(reverse(url_name))
            frequently_asked_questions = FrequentlyAskedQuestion.objects.all()
            response = self.view(request)
            serializer = FrequentlyAskedQuestionSerializer(
                frequently_asked_questions, many=True
            )
            self.assertEqual(response.data, serializer.data)
```

The error is because of this line

```py
    self.view = FrequentlyAskedQuestionView.as_view()
```

but I can't understand what's wrong with it.

Comment: Your TestCase class has the same name and is overriding the imported view, change the name of your TestCase

Comment: It worked, thank you very much